# CRM Online Error Meassage when uploading SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-online

I have modified SSRS report for CRM online, and used some expressions code . after uploading it shows this error message. after searching, Microsoft sayas that this is related to RDLSandbox expression limitation. what is the resolution to make everything work fine without headaces.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5HU4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have copied some textbox to another textbox?
they look like exactly same but,copied value has automatically added name space.
e.g
="funciton you added"～
↓
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction."funciton you added"～

DownLoad Log file,Check the error place and delete name space.
It will works fine.